# App Store video previews - localisation

Tags: ios, iphone, video, app-store-connect

I am trying to A/B test various screenshot sets in the App Store. One of the variants is removing video preview and just keeping the screenshots. However, I have US as the primary language and when I upload the video to itunes connect it automatically defaults to all localizations.

Is there a setting where I show video preview in one location and not the other?

Comment: Hi, have you figured out how to solve this issue? It's 2019, the preview still automatically apply to all language..

Answer (score 1):

## January 9th, 2019 Update

> "You can have up to three app previews for each language your app
>   supports"
>   https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/

After logging into `AppStoreConnect`, selecting your app, selecting `View All Sizes in Media Manager` under the `App Previews and Screenshots` section we're presented with many different configurations for our App's Preview in the AppStore.

On the right, we can choose which locale we'd like to localize for in the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: This is not the issue of the original question. The problem is that setting only one video for US (in example) will show it for every other localisation (like for French or Chinese language)

Comment: It's 2023 and we see a similar problem.  Is anyone able to resolve this ? We suspect that, if the original page has a Preview, the variants must also have a Preview, else Apple shows the original page's Preview.  Reference :  [If you choose not to edit screenshots or previews for a certain device size, the treatment will use the ones on your original product page for that device size](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/create-product-page-optimization-tests/configure-test-treatments)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have different App Previews, you can have only one:

> Uploads must be done using Safari and OS X 10.10, **and only one localization is accepted**. App previews must disclose In-App Purchases and may contain no ads, no platform logos, no pricing, and no timelines.

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10